# Retrying AWS IoT job execution after disconnection

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I have  a device that does some job. For example, downloads some files. At the job execution connection can be lost and it is needed to retry downloading. Is it some mechanisms on AWS IoT that give possibility to retrying job execution? Or how I can retry job execution via aws sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aws-iot-device-sdk-js it wraps mqtt.js and has the capability to of automatic resubscription and backoff retries.